# GROUP BY and ORDER BY date as month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data stored in datetime format i.e. `2016-01-20 03:00:11.000`.

My aim is to display data in Month (string) format and order by month.

**What I want to get (order by Months) -**

```
+----------+-------+
|  Month   | Count |
+----------+-------+
| January  |    87 |
| February |    64 |
| March    |    48 |
| April    |    67 |
| May      |    49 |
+----------+-------+
... rest of months
```

**What I am getting (Ordered by alphabets not months)-**

```
+-----------+-------+
|   Month   | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| April     |    87 |
| August    |    64 |
| December  |    48 |
| February  |    67 |
| January   |    49 |
| July      |    41 |
| June      |    44 |
| March     |    71 |
| May       |    62 |
| November  |    51 |
| October   |    44 |
| September |    48 |
+-----------+-------+
```

**My attempt -**

```
  SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate]) as Month, count([ID]) AS Count
  FROM [dbo].[mytable]
  group by DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
```

**Attempt to order (not working) -**

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate]) as Month, count([mydate]) AS Count
  FROM [dbo].[mytable]
  group by DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
  ORDER BY MONTH([mydate])
```

Getting this error because of aggregate function improperly used

> it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am not sure how to proceed in such scenario. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to group by the month number as well:

```
SELECT   DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate]) as Month,
         count([mydate]) AS DateCount
FROM     [dbo].[mytable]
GROUP BY MONTH([mydate]),
         DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
ORDER BY MONTH([mydate])
```

NB: Don't call your count Count, as it is a reserved word. Use DateCount or something else.

Comment: Your query works fine but when I try to select Month and DateCount with subquery I get this error- The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: There's no requirement to include it in the `select` list. The `group by` and `order by` would be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinSmith is correct, no need to have the month number in the select clause, the important thing is to have it in the group by clause. I updated my answer.

Comment: In long run, your answer helped !

Comment: Glad to hear it did ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have data from one year, then you can do:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, [mydate]) as Month, count([ID]) AS Count
FROM [dbo].[mytable]
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, [mydate])
ORDER BY MIN(mydate);
```

Note:  How well this works, depends on your data.  Trincot's answer is more specific to ordering by the month number.  This orders by the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY
CASE DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
    WHEN 'January' THEN 0
    WHEN 'February' THEN 1
    WHEN 'March' THEN 2
    WHEN 'April' THEN 3
    WHEN 'May' THEN 4
    WHEN 'June' THEN 5
    WHEN 'July' THEN 6
    WHEN 'August' THEN 7
    WHEN 'September' THEN 8
    WHEN 'October' THEN 9
    WHEN 'November' THEN 10
    ELSE 11
END
```

Comment: `MONTH()` returns an integer perfectly suitable for ordering by already. There's absolutely no need to list out all the months as strings like this.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the ideal answer but it worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: @MartinSmith month() fetches the month in string format but doesn't goes well with ORDER BY.

Comment: You're welcome. It is not the most elegant answer but it works with the fields that are already on the OP's select line. Sometimes the most unobtrusive fix, even if less efficient, is the correct one because it reduces the chance that the fix will break something else.

Comment: @PirateX [`MONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) returns an integer not a string, it works fine with ’order by` as shown in the other answers.

Comment: @MartinSmith My mistake, got confused. `Month()` indeed fetches integer but I need to display string(jan,feb) which Datename does. Hence he has used DATENAME. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with window functions and subqueries, like so:

```
select Month, Count
from
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by MONTH([mydate])) as MonthNumber
    , DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
    , count([mydate]) AS Count
      FROM [dbo].[mytable]
      group by DATENAME(MONTH,[mydate])
) results
ORDER BY results.MonthNumber
```

Comment: Getting this error - The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.